# How to set the prefix for all Controller in CI

Tags: codeigniter, controller, routes

I want to set the prefix in **codeiginiter** e.g. my url like this `http:/example.com/233/controller_name/method`. i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351034/add-a-prefix-controller-to-url-in-codeigniter) , but in this topic we need to declare separately endpoint for each url.

```
$route['547/users/auth'] = 'users/auth';
$route['4569/users/create'] = 'users/create';
```

I want to a default `route`  which is ignore the `1 segment` of url. because first segment of url change every time. it is auto-increment id of MySQL table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your `application/config/routes.php` file 

like this `$routes['(:any)/controller_name']='controller_name'`
then your controller will call, and you need the above code for your every controller

Comment: i have problem still i need to declare each and every url `routes`